# How to create a tuple type using polkadot.js api

Tags: polkadot-js, scale-codec, javascript, scale

I am trying to create a tuple. I know we can create an enum by defining the type as

```
   MyEnum: {
            _enum: {
                'account': String,
                'accountId': 'u128'

            }
        }
```

similarly how can i create a tuple type

```
(account, accountId)
```

Comment: For context, why? My impression is usually these should be defined by the node in metadata as opposed to manually crafted . but I admit, in don't use the js libs much 

Answer (score 3):

Tuple types are specified in the same way they are in Rust, i.e. `(AccountId, u32)` will yield a tuple with `AccountId` and `u32`. These are all string values, i.e.

```js
MyTuple: "(AccountId, u32)",
MyEnum: {
  _enum: {
    Foo: "AccountId",
    Bar: "(AccountId, u64)",
    Baz: "String"
  }
}
```

As indicated in a comment, with current Substrate nodes you should not need to define types, these are supplied in the metadata. (There is one caveat - when used over RPCs, these are not available and needs to be manually specified alongside the RPC definitions)