# Add custom type to the substrate-front-end-template

Tags: substrate-front-end, custom-types

is it a new approach to add the custom types to the substrate-front-end-template ?
the ones I found in past examples of Kitties seem don't work any more.
I try adding them to the PolkadotJS and to the config folder into JSON files

Comment: Possible duplicate of:. https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3493/how-to-create-a-tuple-type-using-polkadot-js-api